# proper way to code runge kutta 4th order steps

Tags: python, runge-kutta

`xdot` returns `[dp_dt, dphi_dt]` but the second step of RK4 method doesn't allow `k1` to be called because `k1` is a list...

```
def EOM(s)

    "Equations of Motion"
    p = s[0]
    phi = s[1]
    p_hat = p*b/(2*V)
    C = -0.06*phi+0.033*p_hat+0.073*p_hat**3-0.36*p_hat*phi**2+1.47*p_hat**2*phi
    dp_dt = 1/(2*Ixx)*rho*V**2*S*b*C
    dphi_dt = p 
    sdot = []
    sdot.append(dp_dt)
    sdot.append(dphi_dt)
    return sdot



def rk4(xold):


    xnew = []
    xdot = EOM(xold)
    for i, state in enumerate(xold):
        k1=xdot[i]
        #this is a list of [p,phi] ... how 
        k2=EOM(xold(1)+dt/2,xold(2)+dt/2*k1)
        k3=EOM(xold(1)+dt/2,xold(2)+dt/2*k2)
        k4=EOM(xold(1)+dt,xold(2)+dt*k3)
        xnew.append(state+dt/6*(k1+2*k2+2*k3+k4))
    return xnew
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it is a list. `python` does not do arithmetic vector operations on lists, for that use `numpy` to get arrays that act as vectors.

For an implementation of RK4 without `numpy` see [Solving the Lorentz model using Runge Kutta 4th Order in Python without a package](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53908604/3088138). It is not exactly the same as it uses a list of scalar ODE functions, but the principles should be visible.

Your code can be corrected to work without numpy, but that is only a solution for 2 or 3 variables, with more it becomes error-prone

```py
def rk4(xold):
    k1 = EOM(xold)
    #this is a list of [p_dot,phi_dot]
    k2=EOM(xold[0]+dt/2*k1[0],xold[1]+dt/2*k1[1],) # trailing comma generates list
    k3=EOM([xold[0]+dt/2*k2[0],xold[1]+dt/2*k2[1]]) # or do it directly as list
    k4=EOM([xold[i]+dt*k3[i] for i in [0,1]]) # or use list generation
    return [ xold[i]+dt/6*(k1[i]+2*k2[i]+2*k3[i]+k4[i] for i in [0,1] ]))
```

Comment: so if i change xdot into an array using np.array, how would i be able to call each term of the array into the rk4. ive tried calling k1[0] after changing it into an array, but it says 'list' object is not callable

Comment: You don't. Also, check again what argument is the scalar time and what is the state vector, `EOM` only has the state vector as argument. So you would call `k2 = EOM(xold+0.5*dt*k1)`, provided all tuples are converted to `np.array`.